# Typescript convert object string to date format mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a large array of different objects. They are strings and they come in from the api looking as so

```
const data =   [
      {
        id: 1,
        fruit: “apple”,
        createdOn: "2016-09-02T23:00:00.000Z",
        submittedDate: "2016-09-11T23:00:00.000Z”
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        fruit: “banana”,
        createdOn: "2016-09-11T23:00:00.000Z”,
        submittedDate: "2016-09-11T23:00:00.000Z”
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        fruit: “cherry”,
        createdOn: "2016-09-13T23:00:00.000Z",
        submittedDate: "2016-09-11T23:00:00.000Z”

      },
    ]
 this.gridData = data
```

I assign this object array to a grid that parses out the data. Before I send it to the grid how can I convert these string dates to the format mm/dd/yyyy?

EDIT: So I could have an array of data that has datefields that are created dynamically. Currently in my example I gave you the date field names(createdOn, submittedDate), however I could have an array where I do not know what the field names are.

We do have a way that we can identify these fields as our naming convention requires all date fields to end with "Dt". So since I know a field will be a date based on the string of "Dt" how can I changed the data dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const data = [{
        id: 1,
        fruit: "apple",
        createdOn: "2016-09-02T23:00:00.000Z",
        submittedDate: "2016-09-11T23:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        fruit: "banana",
        createdOn: "2016-09-11T23:00:00.000Z",
        submittedDate: "2016-09-11T23:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        fruit: "cherry",
        createdOn: "2016-09-13T23:00:00.000Z",
        submittedDate: "2016-09-11T23:00:00.000Z"

    },
];

const dataWithDT = [{
        id: 1,
        fruit: "apple",
        createdDt: "2016-09-02T23:00:00.000Z",
        submittedDt: "2016-09-11T23:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        fruit: "banana",
        createdDt: "2016-09-11T23:00:00.000Z",
        submittedDt: "2016-09-11T23:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        fruit: "cherry",
        createdDt: "2016-09-13T23:00:00.000Z",
        submittedDt: "2016-09-11T23:00:00.000Z"

    },
];

function getMMDDYYYY(date) {
    var today = new Date(date);
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

    if (dd < 10)
        dd = '0' + dd
    if (mm < 10)
        mm = '0' + mm
    return mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
}

const formatData = data.map(val => {
    val.createdOn = getMMDDYYYY(val.createdOn);
    val.submittedDate = getMMDDYYYY(val.submittedDate);
    return val;
})

const formatDataWithDt = data.map(val => {
    for (var keys in val) {
        if (keys.includes("Dt")) {
            val[keys] = getMMDDYYYY(val.createdOn);
            val[keys] = getMMDDYYYY(val.submittedDate);
        }
    }
    return val;
})



console.log(formatDataWithDt);
```

Comment: I like this answer now Is there a way that I can change the dates when I do not know the field names? I do know all field names are required to have the text of xxxDt . So it could be tomorrowDt or nextweekDt

Comment: Thanks!. I am not getting your question exactly could you please tell me in more brief? It is good for me to give you accurate answer.

Comment: Sure so I could have an array of data that has datefields that are created dynamically. Currently in my example I gave you the date field names(createdOn, submittedDate), however I could have an array where I do not know what the field names are. There is a way that we can identify these fields as our naming convention requires all date fields to end with Dt. So maybe loop through the array getting all the fields ending in Dt and formatting just those fields only?

Comment: That did it however i did val[keys] = getMMDDYYY(val[keys]); thanks i truly appreciate this

Answer (score 0):

For formating dates in Angular, you can use [Date pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe).

### EDIT

import pipes:

```
import { CurrencyPipe, DatePipe, DecimalPipe } from @angular/common';
```

set them in constructor:

```
constructor(        
        private _curency: CurrencyPipe,
        private _decimal: DecimalPipe,
        private _date: DatePipe,
    ) { }
```

call them in code:

```
let amount = this._decimal.transform(this.invoice.amount, '1.2-2');
```

before: `100`, after `100.00`

```
let date = this._date.transform(this.invocie.date, 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss')
```

before: `2016-09-11T23:00:00.000Z` after: `11.06.2016 23:00:00`

Comment: Ok  so is there anyway to format the array before sending it out to the html? I also am exporting this data array to excel and pdf, however its keeping the data strings. Which is why I wanted to format the array itself.

Comment: @CodeMan03 Yes there is. Please take a look at my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

My method was basically to splice everything together to create any type of format that you wanted.  I would go with a custom pipe in angular though that way you could use it anywhere in your app without having to worry about creating a service to house the method.  That way in your html you could have something like:

```
<p>Here's my date data {{ data.date | myCustomPipe}}</p>
```

At any rate, my solution is as follows although I like the mapping idea a lot more:

```js
const data =   [
      {
        id: 1,
        fruit: 'apple',
        createdOn: "2016-09-02T23:00:00.000Z",
        submittedDate: "2016-09-11T23:00:00.000Z"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        fruit: 'banana',
        createdOn: "2016-09-11T23:00:00.000Z",
        submittedDate: "2016-09-11T23:00:00.000Z"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        fruit: 'cherry',
        createdOn: "2016-09-13T23:00:00.000Z",
        submittedDate: "2016-09-11T23:00:00.000Z"

      },
    ]
this.gridData = data;

changeDateFormat(this.gridData);
printContents();

function changeDateFormat(dataChanging) {
    for(let someData of dataChanging) {
        let year = someData.createdOn.slice(0,4);
        let month = someData.createdOn.slice(5,7);
        let day = someData.createdOn.slice(8,10);
        someData.createdOn = year + '/' + month + '/' + day;
    }
}

function printContents() {
    for(let someData of this.gridData) {
        console.log(someData.createdOn);
    }
}
```